# I'm building googlemap tracking for my app and I'm stuck for over five days now on, I think ,,simple'' problem

Tags: java, android, google-maps, nullpointerexception

I am totally new to Android Studio as well as Java language and I am trying to build an app based on google maps. I will be thankful for detailed solutions.

I've tried onCreateView() and  getChildFragmentManager(). Yet since I am a newbie, I might have done it wrong.

I think the main problem that crashes my app everytime  is

method invocation 'getmapasync' may produce 'nullpointerexception'

## MapsActivity.java

```
package com.example.silentium50;


import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public GoogleMap mMap;

    LocationManager locationManager;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    Activity#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        // check if the network provider is enabled
            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        //get the latitude
                        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        //get the longitude
                        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        //instantiate the class, LatLng
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        //Instantiate the class, Geocoder
                        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                        try {
                            List<Address> adressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                            String str = adressList.get(0).getLocality()+",";
                            str += adressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 30.5f));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                    }
                });
            }
            else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates((LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER), 1, 1, new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        //get the latitude
                        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        //get the longitude
                        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        //instantiate the class, LatLng
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        //Instantiate the class, Geocoder
                        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                        try {
                            List<Address> adressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                            String str = adressList.get(0).getLocality()+",";
                            str += adressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10f));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }





    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 30.5f));
    }
}
```

## activity_maps.xlm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

## Errors after running:

```
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.silentium50-1/lib/x86
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.silentium50, PID: 7103
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.silentium50/com.example.silentium50.MapsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<com.example.silentium50.MapsActivity> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<com.example.silentium50.MapsActivity> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation>
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

## AndroidManifest.xlm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.silentium50">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your full code of your activity and xml file

Comment: sure thing, I will do this in a sec

Comment: @AshwinNirmale
activity_maps.xlm was already full, I've added full activity code and androindmanifest.xlm if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message in the stacktrace I think you might call `new MapsActivity()` somewhere in your code. Is that right?

If so please dont. Instead [build an intent](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#BuildIntent) and start the MapActivity this way.

**Update**: I might be wrong. Can it be that you forget to make your `MapsActivity` public? Please edit the class definition to be `public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {`

Comment: I've shared the full code of my MapsActivity file, there's only one MapsActivity class as far as I am checking it.

And to answer your update my class definition is exactly like that. so I guess it's public, right?

Comment: @PawełOwczarek sorry, copy & paste issue on my side. Please check again. I missed the `public` keyword before the `class` as you. Now it is correct in my answer

Comment: well I thought it works at first because my app runs, but the error with getMapAsync remains the same( at least it shows it may produce NullPointerException) my app runs but doesn't track location, do you have any tips for that? (It doesn't request my permission to locate) I will try to solve it by myself but if u have some free time I will be thankfull for the tip :)

Comment: A fried of mine wrote this little library for exactly that task: https://github.com/P72B/locator-library give it a try :)

Comment: Thank You very much for a quick answer, I will look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

`.getMapAsync()` requires a GoogleMap as the input.  Try changing `.getMapAsync(this)` to `.getMapAsync(mMap)`
Currently `this` is calling MainActivity and not a GoogleMap.

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sadly it didn't help :/ 
error: incompatible types: GoogleMap cannot be converted to OnMapReadyCallback